# Can we set/update a property of ContractState in Contract.verify()?

Tags: corda

I got a doubt that, Can we set/update a property of ContractState in Contract.verify()?

In the flow I am creating an instance of ContractState, and In the same flow I wrote logic of setting one of property of ContractState, based on the fact retreived from Oracle, if the information (say: age) is greater than 60, I am setting 'status' property of ContractState as "Elderly".

And again in Contract.verify() method, I am checking whether the value of status property is "Elderly" if the age is above 60.

So here I am thinking to remove the logic of setting the property value from the flow.call(), and placing this logic inside Contract.verify() method, and checking if the age is > 60, then set 'status' as "Elderly".

Am I allowed to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The `verify` method checks transactions. Once a state has been added to a transaction, it is effectively immutable.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Joel!